# does FF 4 natively support "search for an open tab" feature?

Tags: firefox

When I say search for an already open tab I mean it could be a tab which is already opened in the current tab group or a different tab group which is hidden. I remember seeing a video on this a long time ago - Tab Candy, maybe? But I think that was an add-on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Tab Group view, you should be able to [just start typing](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-are-tab-groups#w_how-do-i-search-through-my-tabs) to search for tabs. If the title of any tab, in any group, matches the search string, that tab will be highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By default you can start typing in the location bar and Firefox will search open tabs, bookmarks and history. Notice that in the screenshot below, I'm performing a search from a tab group that only has a single blank tab. Firefox finds my open Stack Exchange tab even though it's in another tab group:

[image]

You can take this a step further, and search ***only*** open tabs by using the `%` search filter:

[image]

The `%` filter works at the beginning or end of your typing. You can even use it by itself to list all open tabs:

[image]

**Edit:** I've updated this answer to include a number of examples which may be useful to the OP or other passersby. If the Location Bar autocompletion isn't working as expected, it may be due to a configuration issue. The following links provide some information about relevant `about:config` settings, and provide some useful tips for Location Bar autocompletion in general.

[Location Bar Autocomplete page at Mozilla](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Location%20bar%20autocomplete)
[Reference for browser.urlbar.default.behavior setting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.default.behavior)
[Reference for browser.urlbar.matchBehavior setting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.matchBehavior)

Comment: I don't seem to get this...

Comment: Answer edited to include a bunch more info. You seem to have already gotten what you're looking for with the tab group search, but the location bar can be pretty useful too!